# Bubble sort logical error?

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a bubble sort, but I don't know what's happening in my code. I am a noob so sorry if the code I wrote seems obvious ^.^

```
 main() {
        int a[5], i, j, smallest, temp;
        cout << "Enter 5 numbers: " << endl;
        for ( i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ) {
            cin >> a[i];
        }

    for ( i = 0; i <=4; i++ ) {
        smallest = a[i];
        for ( j = 1; j <= 4; j++ ) {
            if ( smallest > a[j] ) {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }


        cout << endl << endl;

        for ( i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ) {
            cout << a[i] << endl;
        }
        system("pause");
    }
```

Any answer will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: This is selection sort, not bubble sort.

Answer (score 1):

Your bubblesort almost appears to be a selection sort. Bubblesort looks at pairs of items and swaps them if necessary. Selection sort looks for the lowest item in the rest of the array, and then swaps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::swap;

void bubblesort(int a[5])
{
    bool swapped = true;
    while (swapped)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
            {
                swap(a[i], a[i + 1]);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

void selectionSort(int a[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int smallest = i;
        for (int j = smallest; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (a[smallest] > a[j])
            {
                smallest = j;
            }
        }
        if (smallest != i)
        {
            swap(a[i], a[smallest]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a[5];
    cout << "Enter 5 numbers: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    //selectionSort(a);
    bubblesort(a);

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ) {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```